# any linux IMAP web client? or something that works similarly to Outlook web Access?

Tags: linux, outlook-web-access, zimbra

is there any Linux software that fetches emails from let's say 3-d party imap server (ex imap.gmail.com) and allows you to access it in nice format through web interface.

So - if I run my own LAMP server I could just type in my ip address and access emails/calendars.

I guess something like Outlook Web Access but free and for Linux?

Is that what Zimbra is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zimbra desktop might do what you want.

*"The free Zimbra Desktop client allows you to meld the online and offline worlds – storing and synching your email, calendar, contacts, files and documents in the cloud, yet having them locally accessible when on the road. Zimbra Desktop aggregates information across accounts (Zimbra, Yahoo! Mail, Gmail, Hotmail, etc.) and social networks (Facebook, Digg, Twitter, etc.) to help make communicating & sharing information easier than ever. "*

http://www.zimbra.com/products/desktop_features.html

For IMAP email with Gmail, Roundcube gets a lot of mentions, but it won't help with calendaring or your address book. I have played with the app in the past and it looks pretty good.

http://roundcube.net/

While I was checking out another possibility, I came across GMDesk - not sure if it does what you want but just in case it's of interest:

http://www.robertnyman.com/gmdesk/